# Global variables in CommonJS (in Brunch)

Tags: javascript, scope, refactoring, commonjs, brunch

I am using [Brunch](http://brunch.io/) to allow CommonJS modules in client side. Problem is how do I define global variables. I know its bad, but I am currently refactoring step by step, so I need access to global variables (window) but it does not work.

In `globals.js`: I define a bunch of global variables for example:

```
window.var1 = "xxx"
```

In a module eg. `chat.js`, I want to use it: simply accessing `var1` does not work ... `window.var1` works, is there a way to treat window as global?

Comment: with(window){ alert(var1); } ? (yuck, i know...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem ... during the refactoring, I refactored:

```
var var1 = 'xxx', 
    var2; // some variables are not initialized
```

to

```
window.var1 = 'xxx';
window.var2; // I think this does nothing, not declaring the variable
```

When I used `var2` it can't be found since its "missing"?